# Form value not change when route change in same component React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have route code in react js

```
<Route path="cms/create/:id" component={ContainerCMS}/>
```

Code in ContainerCMS

```
<div>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Assume i have 2 link `cms/create/staging` and `cms/create/prod` first i visit `cms/create/staging` then filled form but when i visit `cms/create/prod` form value still exist. How to remove it?

Comment: Try wrapping the component in an inline function. `<Route path="cms/create/:id" component={props => <ContainerCMS {...props} />}/>`

Comment: Still filled @levisnkyyyy

Answer (score 0):

add key on component router

```
<Route path="/cms/create/:id" render={props => <ContainerCMS key={props.match.params.id} {...props} />}/>
```